# LyX; how to change the color of the LyX environment choice box

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

The background of this box remains all black no matter which Linux theme I pick, nor can I find any such color in Tools → Preferences → Look & Feel → Colors.

[image: LyX screenshot]

Comment: Try to close Lyx, move ~/.lyx/ somewhere and restart lyx to rebuild the user configuration from the scratch. Otherwise, try to restart Linux after set a new light theme, just in case  that this matter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Fran, thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work.

Comment: oh, I forget that also exists `.config/LyX/`. Try removing both.  If you add a  new user and start a  first  session to just open an close LyX, this will create both directories with the default settings. If the LyX of the new user is showed correctly, then  replace your directories with  that of the new  user should work. In other case, the issue will be in the desktop configuration.

Comment: @Fran, then I guess it's the desktop configuration. Neither method worked. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by installing version 2.4 from aur:
"aur/lyx-git 2.4.Beta1.r369.g109ea2be4a-1 (+7 0.03) (Installed: 2.4.beta2.r993.g8832f816ce-1)"